# Vue shows ugly console error on custom throw

Tags: vue.js

I've custom throw at component created() method.

```
throw new Error(`Cookie ${cookieName} not exist.`);
```

And vue logs it into console:
`[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: Cookie showLanguageInfo not exist."`

How can I implement throwing this error without this vue log?

Comment: can you provide more code. It's unclear with this general code.

Comment: Does this message also pop up when you build your code and deploy it? Webpack does removes a lot of Vue notifications when you use the vue cli to generate your build files. Additionally to that you could have a look at the global options for the error handler, and do something with error messages before processing them: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann Yup project was generated via cli, dev server gives nothing, only console in browser

Comment: Why throw the error there if you don't want to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the below line from `created` hook. The below line is throwing error without any real exception.

```
throw console.error("error");
```